# Resilient file or directory linking or automatic link updating?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, links, hardlink, mklink

Is there a file or directory link method that would be dynamic/resilient against target change?

I mean if I create a link `mklink /d test c:\test` I can change the link name after but not rename/move the target dir or else the connection will break and the link must be replaced.

This might be acceptable in a stable dir tree structure but this one is very much in a constant state of flux where some sort of automation is required.

Comment: Then use a script as part of the change mechanism.

Comment: @RohitGupta A link to a script that tracks the pairing? It would have to be something that looks like a directory to applications.

Comment: You'll have to provide some information or examples of how the structure is changing. It's easy enough to script `rmdir $oldlink; mklink /d $newlink c:\newfolder`, but how should it know the difference between renamed and deleted/new folders for example?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might want to use: environment variables, fixing your `path`, a separate file list (or database, at scale), integrating with whatever process via script, or even just turn it into a git-style repo and let git track changes

Comment: Is the "state of flux" because of archiving?

Comment: Directory contains files of every subject in the world so renaming and relocating directories happens a whole lot. Imagine sorting music by genre while you're figuring out all the possible genres.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there exists no file-system that can track the target
file (or folder) of a symbolic link when it's moved.
Moving the target always invalidates the link.

Some archiving systems can track files as they are moved automatically
between storage media, but this does not apply here.

My suggestion would be to adopt another and parallel system for finding
your files when they are moved between folders, independent of their
current location.

A very basic method would be to use meta-tags of Windows Explorer,
in addition to your folder structure.
You may use standard known tags such as Author, Album or Artist,
but you may also create your own tags. You may then use the Search field
in Explorer for finding your files.
Note that these tags can only be used in NTFS disks and will be lost if
copied to, for example, FAT32.

For more information, see for example the article
[How to Add and Use Tags in Windows 10?](https://www.webnots.com/how-to-add-and-use-tags-in-windows-10/)

There exist more sophisticated file-cataloging products, such as
Windows Media Player and its media library, but I can't recommend
any from my personal knowledge.